# Uniform convergence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2-n^4}{n^5+n^3+1}\left(x^2\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\right)^n$. Troubling finding the interval.

Tags: power-series, uniform-convergence

I have to find the interval of uniform convergence, for the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2-n^4}{n^5+n^3+1}\left(x^2\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\right)^n$$

Now my attempt has been to use the quotient (ratio) test to find the interval on which the series converges, so that I can find an upper bound. Taking the quotient test gives me the following:

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\rightarrow \left|x^2\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\right|,   n \rightarrow \infty$$

Therefore the series must be absolutely convergent on when
$$\left|x^2\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)\right| < 1$$

However since this doesn't give me an upper bound, I'm stuck. The assignment offers me a few options to pick from, and there are no interval options above or below $\pm\sqrt{2}$, so I know that while there are intervals around all even numbers of $x$ these are not useful, though I do not know why. What am I missing?

Comment: $\left| x^2 \sin \left( \frac{\pi x}{2} \right) \right| < 1$ where $-1 < x < 1$, as well as on some discontinuous intervals further away from the origin. Is $(-1, 1)$ an option?

Comment: it is not. the options are:

$x \in [\frac{1}{2},1]$,

$x \in [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$,

$x \in [0,1[$,

$x \in [-1,-\frac{1}{2}]$,

$x \in [0,\sqrt{2}]$,

$x \in [-\sqrt{2},0]$,